# How to set linespacing for a document created from scratch using using docx4j api?

Tags: java, docx4j

I have been trying to create a word document using Docx4j, java API and set the linespacing, but am unable to find the API to set the same. Can anyone help me on this?

```
Java Code  
        P paragraph = factory.createP();

        Text text = factory.createText();
        text.setValue(content);

        if(content.equals("")){
            text.setSpace("   ");
        }

        R run = factory.createR();
        run.getContent().add(text);

        paragraph.getContent().add(run);

        RPr runProperties = factory.createRPr();


        if (bold) {
            addBoldStyle(runProperties);
        }

        if (fontSize != null && !fontSize.isEmpty()) {
            setFontAndFontSize(runProperties, fontSize);
        }

        run.setRPr(runProperties);


        PPr pPR = factory.createPPr();
        Spacing spacing = factory.createPPrBaseSpacing();
        spacing.setAfter(new BigInteger("0"));
        spacing.setBefore(new BigInteger("0"));
        pPR.setSpacing(spacing);

        **I WANT TO SET THE LINE SPACING SOMEWHERE HERE**

        paragraph.setPPr(pPR);

        tableCell.getContent().add(paragraph);


The xml for the generated doc is as follows.

`<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:before="1" w:after="1"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
        <w:rPr>
            <w:rFonts w:ascii="Trade Gothic LT Std" w:hAnsi="Trade Gothic LT Std"/>
            <w:b w:val="true"/>
            <w:sz w:val="14"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="14"/>
        </w:rPr>
        <w:t xml:space=""></w:t>
    </w:r>
</w:p>
<w:p>
    <w:pPr>
        <w:spacing w:before="1" w:after="1"/>
    </w:pPr>
    <w:r>
    <w:rPr>
        <w:rFonts w:ascii="Trade Gothic LT Std" w:hAnsi="Trade Gothic LT Std"/>
            <w:sz w:val="14"/>
            <w:szCs w:val="14"/>
    </w:rPr>
    <w:t>XXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX XXXXXXXXXXX.</w:t>
</w:r>
</w:p>`
```

I want to set linespacing between every paragraph. How to do this?
Also in case of new line, the test is getting set as 
I want this to be displayed as plain text or be able to assign it a font and size. Is this also possible?

Comment: could you post some code to see how you are painting lines, in general you will have to add line spacing above or beneath the line rect

Comment: @whyn0t - I have edited the question to include the piece of java code.

Comment: why are you using BigInteger as spacing unit ? and as I see spacing is already set on your paragraph propoerties, line spacing is an attribute interpreted by the view while painting the content, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/StyleConstants.html

Comment: BigInt is used since that is the unit it accepts. Also, this is to set the initial space in a paragraph. This doesn't set the line space. my line space is at 1.15 and I need to set it to 1.

Comment: try this one www.programcreek.com/java-api-examples/index.php?api=org.docx4j.wml.PPrBase ;

Comment: Have you tried generating code using the docx4j webapp or Docx4jHelper Word AddIn?

Comment: @whyn0t  -The link says it is nit a popularly used API and has not data.

Comment: @JasonPlutext I haven't generated code usingthe webapp/addin, but I need the Java API. Doesn't the webapp display only the openxml for the same?

Comment: I have edited the edited the question to add the code. There is an additional question I have now. Both are in the original question.

Comment: Found a workaround. I created a template and set the default linespacing to 1 which did the trick, but I am still left with the other question. I have a space field for which the font and its size doesn't get set. the set parameters doesn't seem to take into effect. Is there any way I can set

Comment: Use the docx4j webapp or Docx4jHelper Word AddIn to generate suitable Java code from a sample docx

Comment: I did, an empty space has not settings. Also, I apply the same style and or font and size for the space, but it doesn't take into effect. Looks like settings cannot be applied for a space.

Comment: Can you check and let me know if you are able to apply style(font and size) to a space in a word document. i doubt it can be done, unless there is some text.

Comment: @JasonPlutext - Is there a different API to set font and size for a space?

Comment: What do you mean when you talk about a space?  You can set rPr properties on a run which contains " "; you can also set w:pPr/w:rPr, which is the run properties for the paragraph mark:  http://webapp.docx4java.org/OnlineDemo/ecma376/WordML/rPr_1.html